# Wireshark interfaces

Tags: wireshark

Running Arch linux, wireshark installed via pacman. I am a member of the network and the wireshark groups, and have not only logged out but have completely rebooted the computer since adding myself to those groups. Permissions on dumpcap are set, and setcap run (several times.) I can run dumpcap directly via CLI from my normal user and capture packets:

```
╰─❯ groups
tty network wireshark libvirt docker users uucp optical disk audio wheel ddjones

╰─❯ ls -l /usr/bin/dumpcap
-rwsr-x--- 1 root wireshark 116928 Jun  7 15:16 /usr/bin/dumpcap

╰─❯ getcap /usr/bin/dumpcap
/usr/bin/dumpcap cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw=eip

─❯ dumpcap
Capturing on 'enp6s0'
File: /tmp/wireshark_enp6s09ZS040.pcapng
Packets captured: 37
Packets received/dropped on interface 'enp6s0': 37/0 (pcap:0/dumpcap:0/flushed:0/ps_ifdrop:0) (100.0%)
```

If I run wireshark via sudo, I see the local network interfaces. If I run it as my normal user, all I see are ciscodump, dpausmon, ranpkt, sdjournal, sshdump and udpdump. Everything I can find says to set the perms and caps on dumpcap, and I should be able to see ethernet interfaces inside Wireshark. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the [pcap group](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530920/tcpdump-permissions-problem) to your user if it exists

```
usermod -aG pcap "$USER"
```

Answer (score 0):

That's...

...odd.

dumpcap is set-uid root, which should be sufficient to open capture devices, and also has cap_net_raw, which should *also* be sufficient to open capture devices.  Wireshark relies on dumpcap to do capturing and to find out what devices exist, so it should see all the devices.

Furthermore, libpcap has, for a while, been able to get lists of devices without requiring the ability to open them, so even if dumpcap weren't set-uid root and didn't have cap_net_raw, Wireshark still should *show* you the devices, but just wouldn't let you capture on them.

You should report this as an issue on [the Wireshark issues list](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/issues), so this can be debugged.  Please provide full version information when reporting it.